# Apply root motion and gravity for rigid body

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have set a "apply root motion" animation for a gameobject. But it flies when animation starts.

GameObject only has rigidbody, collider. and it animates as fab clone.

How can i make that object go down with gravity.

E.G. There is a road and a car. car normally animates good on the road. but if i enable rigid body car begins flying like a plane

Comment: Make that object go down with gravity -> And if you use the gravity setting of the rigidbody ?

Comment: where is that? normally it selcted with use gravity

Comment: also their wieght is 100s

Answer (score 0):

You should use the "Use gravity" setting in the rigidbody if you want to add gravity.
Note that you need a collider to apply the weight.

If you are doing an animation, i recommend adding one (or more) collider and one **kinematic** rigidody. That way, you can easily create rag-dolls and stuff like that.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4N1HRxyCwB4 i am thinking about doing a game like this but in that game is the car moving or the road is moving i am confused

Comment: Search for "Endless runner tutorial" in your favorite search engine